# how to add number of days to the date given in a jtextfield with string data type

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, gregorian-calendar

Good Day .
I just wanna ask about adding days in a given date.
I have a jtexfield (txtStart) and another jtexfield(txtExpiry).
I need to display in txtExpiry the date after 102 days from the date in txtStart.
I am using KEYRELEASED event. after i input in txtStart, the date with additional 102 days shall appear in txtExpiry.

here's my code but it's still erroneous.

```
private void txtStartKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
    // set calendar to 1 Jan 2007
    int a = Integer.parseInt(txtStart.getText());     
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(a,a,a);

     calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,102);
     PrintCalendar(calendar);
  }

   private void PrintCalendar(Calendar calendar){
        // define output format and print
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");         
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        long add = Date.parse(date);
        txtExpiry.setText(add);  -----> this part here also has an error.
     }
```

my code still won't generate the date in txtExpiry. Thanks in advance

Here's the right code after receiving help:

```
 private void txtStartKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
       try {    

        Date date1;
        date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(txtStart.getText());
        System.out.println(date1);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");     
        Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
                      cal.setTime(date1);
                        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 102);
                        String expDateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                        txtExpiry.setText(expDateString);
     }catch (ParseException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(ClientInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } 
}
```

Comment: What's the error being thrown? Doesn't the setText method only take a String parameter? Looks like you're giving it a long.

Comment: error ---> method setText cannot be applied to given datatypes.  what should i use? i needed the output to be placed in txtExpiry

Comment: You should be just able to take your date variable (which is a String) and pass it to your txtExpiry.setText(date).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

**Note: Capital MM**

See : [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Now, once you have the date instance you could use `Calendar` to do the days arithmetic

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(parsedDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 102);
String expDateString = dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: int a = Integer.parseInt(txtStart.getText());     
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(a,a,a);
this part here i think is also wrong. because i am just getting the date value from txtStart. how can i extract the date here and use it in calendar?

Comment: I assume you have date in String form in the jTextField for example : `1987-12-24` , now you could use `SimpleDateFormat` to get the String to `Date` and  `Date` to `Calendar`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the correct [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you could use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).  You could parse the `String` value directly using JodaTime, but since you've already done that, I've not bothered...

```
Date date = ...;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
dt = dt.plusDays(102);
date = dt.toDate();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
class ISCprac2009q01{
public static void main(String args[])
throws InputMismatchException{

Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("ENTER DAY NUMER(>=1 AND
 <=366) : ");
int day_number=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("ENTER YEAR(4 DIGIT) : ");
int year=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("ENTER DATE AFTER(N)(>=1 AND
 <=100) : ");
int n=scan.nextInt();

if(day_number<1 || day_number>366)
System.out.println("INVALID DAY NUMBER.");
else if(year<1000 || year >9999)
System.out.println("INVALID YEAR");
else if(n<1 || n>100)
System.out.println("INVALID DATE AFTER VALUE.");
else{
//INITIALIZE MONTH NAMES AND NUMBER OF DAYS IN EACH MONTH
    String month_names[]={"JANUARY", "FEBRUARY","MARCH",
        "APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER",
        "OCTOBER","NOVERMBER","DECEMBER"};
    int month_days[]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int i, day, month,day_after;
    String suffix;

   //IF IT IS A LEAP YEAR FEBRURAY SHOULD HAVE 29 DAYS
    if(year%400==0 || (year%100!=0 && year%4==0))
        month_days[1]=29;

        i=0;
   //FIND THE DATE CORRESPONDING TO THE DAY NUMBER
        day=day_number;
        while(day>month_days[i])
        {
            day-=month_days[i];
            i++;
        }
        month=i;
        //ADD SUFFIX AS PER THE DAY
        if(day%10==1 && day/10!=1)
            suffix="ST";
        else if(day%10==2 && day/10!=1)
            suffix="ND";
        else if(day%10==3 && day/10!=1)
            suffix="RD";
        else
            suffix="TH";
        System.out.println("OUTPUT:");
        //FIRST PART OF THE OUTPUT
        System.out.println(day+suffix+" "+
        month_names[month]+" "+year);

        //TO CALCULATE DATE AFTER N DAYS
        day_after=day_number+n;
        i=0;
        while(day_after>month_days[i])
        {
            day_after-=month_days[i];
            i++;
            if(i==12){
            i=0;
            year++;
            if(year%400==0 || (year%100!=0 && year%4==0))
                month_days[1]=29;
            }
        }
        day=day_after;
        month=i;
        //ADD SUFFIX AS PER THE DAY
        if(day%10==1 && day/10!=1)
            suffix="ST";
        else if(day%10==2 && day/10!=1)
            suffix="ND";
        else if(day%10==3 && day/10!=1)
            suffix="RD";
        else
            suffix="TH";
       //SECOND PART OF THE OUTPUT
        System.out.println(day+suffix+" "+
        month_names[month]+" "+year);
}
}
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP question and moreover there is no need to write so much code just to calculate a date N number of days ahead. Please check the accepted answer.